# Binding grid after generating pdf and creating download

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I  have a page with grid that generates PDF files using iTextSharp dll. The code is as following:

```
  var document = new Document();
                            bool download = true;
                            if (download == true)
                            {
                                PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
                                BindGrid();
                            }
                            string fileName = "PDF" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".pdf";
                            try
                            {

                                document.Open();
                                // adding contents to the pdf file....
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                lblMessage.Text = ex.ToString();
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                document.Close();
                                BindGrid();
                            }
                            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
                            Response.Flush();
                            Response.End();
                            BindGrid();
                        }
```

I need to bind the grid once the download window pops up, or after user clicks to download it doesn't matters, I just need the grid to bind after the user generates the pdf file. I have tried binding the grid on numerous places as you can see, but none of them worked, the grid binds only after I refresh the page :(.

Is there any way I can do this ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response.End ends the page life cycle.

I suggest you to:

1. Generate the PDF file and save it on the server
2. Bind the grid
3. Flush the generated file

Something like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            BindGrid(); // Bind the grid here

        // After reloading the page you flush the file
        if (Session["FILE"] != null)
            FlushFile();
    }

    protected void gv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        // Generate & Save PDF here

        Session["FILE"] = fullFilePath; // The full path of the file you saved.

        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl); // This reload the page
    }

    private void FlushFile()
    {
        string fullFilePath = Session["FILE"].ToString();
        Session["FILE"] = null; 

        // Flush file here
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Comment: Check the edited answer. I didn't tested it, but it should work.